# When I run a rails test can I make it display only the error message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I am following along with the Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl and am up to the point of running tests.  The test is a simple "supposed to fail" test shown here:

```
test "should get about" do
  get static_pages_about_url
  assert_response :success
end
```

with the error being simply that the `about` page, controller method, and route do not yet exist.  However when I run the test I get a massive block of code which fills up my terminal.  This is just a small sampling as an example of what i'm seeing.

```
E

Error:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_about:
NameError: undefined local variable or method `static_pages_about_url' for #<StaticPagesControllerTest:0x00007fe6682cc760 @_routes=nil, @NAME="test_should_get_about", @failures=[#<Minitest::UnexpectedError: Unexpected exception>], @assertions=0, @integration_session=#<#<Class:0x00007fe6685342c8>:0x00007fe66859fc58 @_routes=nil, @app=#<SampleApp::Application:0x000055d7735cea68 @_all_autoload_paths=["/home/clay/Programs/sample_app/app/channels", "/home/clay/Programs/sample_app/app/controllers", "/home/clay/Programs/sample_app/app/controllers/concerns", "/home/clay/Programs/sample_app/app/helpers", "/home/clay/Programs/sample_app/app/jobs", "/home/clay/Programs/sample_app/app/mailers", "/home/clay/Programs/sample_app/app/models", "/home/clay/Programs/sample_app/app/models/concerns"], @_all_load_paths=["/home/clay/Programs/sample_app/lib", "/home/clay/Programs/sample_app/vendor", "/home/clay/Programs/sample_app/app/channels", "/home/clay/Programs/sample_app/app/controllers", "/home/clay/Programs/sample_app/app/controllers/concerns", "/home/clay/Programs/sample_app/app/helpers", "/home/clay/Programs/sample_app/app/jobs", "/home/clay/Programs/sample_app/app/mailers", "/home/clay/Programs/sample_app/app/models", "/home/clay/Programs/sample_app/app/models/concerns"], @app=#<ActionDispatch::HostAuthorization:0x000055d774009820 @app=#<Rack::Sendfile:0x000055d774009988 @app=#<ActionDispatch::Static:0x000055d773fe4f98 @app=#<ActionDispatch::Executor:0x000055d773fe5088 @app=#<ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware:0x000055d77382f4d8 @name="ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache", @local_cache_key=:active_support_cache_null_store_local_cache_4420, @app=#<Rack::Runtime:0x000055d773fe51f0 @app=#<Rack::MethodOverride:0x000055d773fe5290 @app=#<ActionDispatch::RequestId:0x000055d773fe5330 @app=#<ActionDispatch::RemoteIp:0x000055d773fe5420 @app=#<Rails::Rack::Logger:0x000055d773fe54e8 @app=#<ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions:0x000055d773fe5588 @app=#<ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions:0x000055d773fe56c8 @app=#<ActionDispatch::ActionableExceptions:0x000055d773fe5790 @app=#<ActionDispatch::Reloader:0x000055d773fe58f8 @app=#<ActionDispatch::Callbacks:0x000055d773fe5998 @app=#<ActionDispatch::Cookies:0x000055d773fe5a38 @app=#<ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore:0x000055d773fe5c68 @app=#<ActionDispatch::ContentSecurityPolicy::Middleware:0x000055d773fe5d58 @app=#<ActionDispatch::PermissionsPolicy::Middleware:0x000055d773fe5e20 @app=#<Rack::Head:0x000055d773fe5ec0 @app=#<Rack::ConditionalGet:0x000055d773fe5f60 @app=#<Rack::ETag:0x000055d773fe6050 @app=#<Rack::TempfileReaper:0x000055d773fe60f0
```

All I really need is the `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'static_pages_about_url'` and the location of the failing test right?  Is this standard for failing tests in Ruby on Rails or is there a way to change how error messages are displayed from showing all of this less useful information?

Comment: What you're seeing isn't actually a test failure - its your code blowing up with an unhandled exception. Suppressing the stack trace is just going to make it harder to solve the issue. This can sound kind of strange if your not used to the red/green cycle but your job here is really to just get the test to the stage where it actually runs to completion without raising an exception (but is still failing) and then ensure that the test passes.

Comment: An example of failing test would be "Expected status to be 200 - OK but was 404 Not Found". If you want to write the test as red/green you would use `get  '/about'` or whatever the path is. That way you can write the test before you implement the route. I appreachiate that Hartl includes testing in his book but the revision where he switched from RSpec to Minitest was not good.

Comment: So for the "red" part of the red/green cycle is this what i'm supposed to be seeing?  It just seems like a LOT of code to show me the error stack trace, when for the red/green cycle i'm SUPPOSED to see it fail.  Is this what a failing test is supposed to look like, massive block of code and all?

Comment: No - a red test would show you "expected x to be y". This is your test blowing up and once you get more complex problems that stack trace is important.

Answer (score -2):

In test driven development (TDD), you write the tests first. When you run them, all of them will be failing because you have not written the implementation yet (this is your "Red"). After that, you write the implementation that makes the tests pass (this is your "Green"). Once all tests are passsing, it comes the stage where you refactor the implementation (if required, this is your "Refactor"). Red, Green, Refactor.

In your particular example, you have written the test that checks if you can "GET" the about page but because you have not yet implemented the solution, your tests are failing.

In order to make the test pass, you'll need to add this to your route.rb file.

```
get  'static_pages/about'
```

Comment: It is exactly a failing test, and also my suggestion will make his test pass. You can read more from Michael Hartl's book here - https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#sec-green

Comment: The error is a NoMethodError because he's calling a route that isn't defined and this doesn't even adress that. I did read Hartl's book. 10 years ago...